# tangible intelligence

Tags: artificial-intelligence, business-intelligence

I am afraid this question is not supposed to be asked here but I have spent lots of time over google and didn't find anything fruitful so just need to know from here if anyone can help me in finding this thing. some search phrase that could help or some website.

I want to know if `Intelligence is tangible or not?` I think it is and Artificial Intelligence is an example but, I need to get some examples or reason for it that am unable to find. looking for some website links or a phrase to search over google.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot touch intelligence so it is by definition intangible.

Depending of your definitions of "intelligence" and "tangible"  there aree edge cases where it could be said that intelligence is tangible e.g. If a spy obtained a photograph of a bomb factory it could be said you have "tangible intelligence" but this is really just a play on words.

I presume you are talking of some legal definition of "tangible" (i.e. does intelligence count as "tangible property") but this would depend on which legal system we are talking about as its not universally accepted term and various jurisdictions have different interpretations of the phrase.

In some jurisdictions an Artificial Intelligence system could be said to be "tangable" in that it can be copyrighted but this is not the same as "intelligence".

Comment: Thanks James for the reply its making sense to me :)

well just think of something, can we say an IQ test result of a person be evidence of his intelligence that is tangible? or any result from him measuring intelligence level

Comment: IQ is based on the rates at which intelligence develops in children. It is the ratio of the age at which a child normally makes a certain score to the child's age. The scale is extended to adults in a suitable way. IQ correlates well with various measures of success or failure in life, but making computers that can score high on IQ tests would be weakly correlated with their usefulness.

Comment: For example, the ability of a child to repeat back a long sequence of digits correlates well with other intellectual abilities, perhaps because it measures how much information the child can compute with at once. However, ``digit span'' is trivial for even extremely limited computers.
However, some of the problems on IQ tests are useful challenges for AI.
Therefore, IQ might work to some extent in human beings (though highly criticized), but does not on other supports, such as computers.

Answer (score 3):

The difficulty of your question stems from the definition of intelligence. No consensus on a formal definition of intelligence has been reached by scholars so far. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence for further attempts of definition.

[JMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_McCarthy_%28computer_scientist%29) used to say intelligence is the computational part of the ability to achieve goals in the world. Varying kinds and degrees of intelligence occur in people, many animals and some machines.

I mostly agree with this definition, which among other things emphasizes the fact that intelligence occurs **gradually**. Therefore, I believe you must set some kind of threshold above which you consider a behavior as intelligent. This is not easy task as AFAIK there is no way to compare intelligence except on specific tasks.

There is no solid definition of intelligence that doesn't depend on relating it to human intelligence. As [JMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_McCarthy_%28computer_scientist%29) points out, the problem is that we cannot yet characterize in general what kinds of computational procedures we want to call intelligent. As a result, your threshold will probably refers to level of intelligence in human beings (which in turn is not obvious, cf. the debates on IQ).

You may want to read [Computing Machinery and Intelligence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_Machinery_and_Intelligence), written by Alan Turing and published in 1950, as well as check out this general [FAQ](http://ai-faq.com/) on AI.

Answer (score 1):

It is not tangible yet. This is the main reason that we don't have Artificial Intelligence that can pass the Turing Test yet. This is probably a bad place to ask this question, philosophy forums might be better.